# telerik <clientitemtemplate> parsing error

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik, telerik-grid

i am developing application using telerik.web.ui library, i have copy code from its demo but it is showing ***PARSING ERROR*** i have also added xhtml11.dtd 
my code is

```
<telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadGrid1" runat="server"     AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowMultiRowSelection="true">

<MasterTableView ClientDataKeyNames="CustomerID" TableLayout="Fixed">
                <Columns>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ContactName" UniqueName="ContactName" HeaderText="Name">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="InfoClientTemplateColumn" HeaderText="Customer Info">
                        <clientitemtemplate>
                        <img id="customerPhoto" height="100" width="82" src="ImageHandler.ashx?custID= #=CustomerID#" alt="#=ContactName#" />
                        <br />
<a href="#= String.format(searchUrlFormat, ContactName) #">Search Google for <em>#=ContactName#</em></a>
                    </clientitemtemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                   </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: change <clientitemtemplate> to <ItemTemplate> . Check documentation for more details. http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/columns/column-types#gridtemplatecolumn

Comment: i have copy from[completely]   http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-binding/client-side/client-item-template/defaultvb.aspx?show-source=true       then an then i got this error i have also applied local dtd but its not working    *i am using client side service binding so have to must use clientitemtemplate.